# what's the way to retrieve data from comma separated from s single column?

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

I am trying to retrieve cat id in product table from product_category.

controller.php

```
$shop['product'] = Product::with('ProductImages')->where('product_status','=',1)->where('product_drop_status','=','no')->where('language_code','=',$translate)->whereRaw('find_in_set(cat-,product.product_category)')->orderBy('product_id','desc')->get();
```

I need to retrieve value "19". what's wrong in controller??

Comment: The FIND_IN_SET() function returns the position of a string within a list of strings. In your case can return 1;

Comment: what should i do to retrive ''19'' ?? any sugesstion

Comment: If you want to find products by ->whereRaw('find_in_set(cat-,product.product_category)') will have to add the category id in `->whereRaw('find_in_set(cat-19,product.product_category)')`

Answer (score 0):

On your Product model you can set an attribute:

```
public function setCatIdAttribute(){
    $chunks = explode(',', $this->product_category);
    foreach($chunks as $chunk){
        if (strpos($chunk, 'cat-') !== false) {
            return str_replace('cat-', '', $chunk);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

On your collection you can access like this:

```
foreach($products as $product){
    echo $product->cat_id;
}
```

Comment: it is not woking